# Detect changes in the ContentPlaceHolder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web

Is there any jquery event to detect changes in the ContentPlaceHolder ?
Thanks

```html
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: In JS or ASP.Net?

Comment: In Jquery/javascript.. thnx

Comment: Assuming there's no alternative you could use a [MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Comment: Ok thanks.. I ll look into it.